# go: writing stat cache: mkdir /User: read-only file system

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

You get this error while installing go pkg in VS code.It tries to create cache dir under /User which is obviously read only and we should change the permission of it.
The pkgs which failes-

Installing 10 tools at /User/ajayk/code/go/bin in module mode.
gopkgs
go-outline
gotests
gomodifytags
impl
goplay
dlv
dlv-dap
staticcheck
gopls

```
Tools environment: GOPATH=/User/ajayk/code/go
Installing 10 tools at /User/ajayk/code/go/bin in module mode.
  gopkgs
  go-outline
  gotests
  gomodifytags
  impl
  goplay
  dlv
  dlv-dap
  staticcheck
  gopls

Installing github.com/uudashr/gopkgs/v2/cmd/gopkgs FAILED
{
 "killed": false,
 "code": 1,
 "signal": null,
 "cmd": "/usr/local/go/bin/go get -v github.com/uudashr/gopkgs/v2/cmd/gopkgs",
 "stdout": "",
 "stderr": "go: downloading github.com/uudashr/gopkgs v1.3.2\ngo: writing stat cache: mkdir /User: read-only file system\ngo: downloading github.com/uudashr/gopkgs/v2 v2.1.2\ngo get github.com/uudashr/gopkgs/v2/cmd/gopkgs: mkdir /User: read-only file system\n"
}
Installing github.com/ramya-rao-a/go-outline FAILED
{
 "killed": false,
 "code": 1,
 "signal": null,
 "cmd": "/usr/local/go/bin/go get -v github.com/ramya-rao-a/go-outline",
 "stdout": "",
 "stderr": "go: downloading github.com/ramya-rao-a/go-outline v0.0.0-20200117021646-2a048b4510eb\ngo get github.com/ramya-rao-a/go-outline: mkdir /User: read-only file system\n"
}
Installing github.com/cweill/gotests/gotests FAILED
{
 "killed": false,
 "code": 1,
 "signal": null,
 "cmd": "/usr/local/go/bin/go get -v github.com/cweill/gotests/gotests",
 "stdout": "",
 "stderr": "go: writing stat cache: mkdir /User: read-only file system\ngo: downloading github.com/cweill/gotests v1.6.0\ngo get github.com/cweill/gotests/gotests: mkdir /User: read-only file system\n"
}
Installing github.com/fatih/gomodifytags FAILED
{
 "killed": false,
 "code": 1,
 "signal": null,
 "cmd": "/usr/local/go/bin/go get -v github.com/fatih/gomodifytags",
 "stdout": "",
 "stderr": "go: writing stat cache: mkdir /User: read-only file system\ngo: downloading github.com/fatih/gomodifytags v1.13.0\ngo get github.com/fatih/gomodifytags: mkdir /User: read-only file system\n"
}
Installing github.com/josharian/impl FAILED
{
 "killed": false,
 "code": 1,
 "signal": null,
 "cmd": "/usr/local/go/bin/go get -v github.com/josharian/impl",
 "stdout": "",
 "stderr": "go: writing stat cache: mkdir /User: read-only file system\ngo: downloading github.com/josharian/impl v1.0.0\ngo get github.com/josharian/impl: mkdir /User: read-only file system\n"
}
Installing github.com/haya14busa/goplay/cmd/goplay FAILED
{
 "killed": false,
 "code": 1,
 "signal": null,
 "cmd": "/usr/local/go/bin/go get -v github.com/haya14busa/goplay/cmd/goplay",
 "stdout": "",
 "stderr": "go: writing stat cache: mkdir /User: read-only file system\ngo: downloading github.com/haya14busa/goplay v1.0.0\ngo get github.com/haya14busa/goplay/cmd/goplay: mkdir /User: read-only file system\n"
}
Installing github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv FAILED
{
 "killed": false,
 "code": 1,
 "signal": null,
 "cmd": "/usr/local/go/bin/go get -v github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv",
 "stdout": "",
 "stderr": "go: writing stat cache: mkdir /User: read-only file system\ngo: downloading github.com/go-delve/delve v1.6.1\ngo get github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv: mkdir /User: read-only file system\n"
}
Installing github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@master FAILED
{
 "killed": false,
 "code": 1,
 "signal": null,
 "cmd": "/usr/local/go/bin/go get -v -d github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@master",
 "stdout": "",
 "stderr": "go: writing stat cache: mkdir /User: read-only file system\ngo: writing stat cache: mkdir /User: read-only file system\ngo: downloading github.com/go-delve/delve v1.6.2-0.20210528182153-b2afb7cd209e\ngo get github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@master: mkdir /User: read-only file system\n"
}
Installing honnef.co/go/tools/cmd/staticcheck FAILED
{
 "killed": false,
 "code": 1,
 "signal": null,
 "cmd": "/usr/local/go/bin/go get -v honnef.co/go/tools/cmd/staticcheck",
 "stdout": "",
 "stderr": "go: writing stat cache: mkdir /User: read-only file system\ngo: downloading honnef.co/go/tools v0.2.0\ngo get honnef.co/go/tools/cmd/staticcheck: mkdir /User: read-only file system\n"
}
Installing golang.org/x/tools/gopls FAILED
{
 "killed": false,
 "code": 1,
 "signal": null,
 "cmd": "/usr/local/go/bin/go get -v golang.org/x/tools/gopls",
 "stdout": "",
 "stderr": "go: writing stat cache: mkdir /User: read-only file system\ngo: writing stat cache: mkdir /User: read-only file system\ngo: downloading golang.org/x/tools v0.1.2\ngo: downloading golang.org/x/tools/gopls v0.6.11\ngo get golang.org/x/tools/gopls: mkdir /User: read-only file system\n"
}

10 tools failed to install.
```

Answer (score 0):

The quick workaround is, install these packages from the terminal directly in your gopath. Once installed, check your pkg in gopath.

```
ajayk@ajays-MacBook-Pro-2 code % /usr/local/go/bin/go get -v github.com/uudashr/gopkgs/v2/cmd/gopkgs
go: downloading github.com/uudashr/gopkgs v1.3.2
go: downloading github.com/uudashr/gopkgs/v2 v2.1.2
go: downloading github.com/uudashr/gopkgs v2.0.1+incompatible
go: downloading github.com/karrick/godirwalk v1.12.0
go: downloading github.com/pkg/errors v0.8.1
github.com/pkg/errors
github.com/karrick/godirwalk
github.com/uudashr/gopkgs/v2
github.com/uudashr/gopkgs/v2/cmd/gopkgs
ajayk@ajays-MacBook-Pro-2 code % /usr/local/go/bin/go get -v github.com/ramya-rao-a/go-outline
go: downloading github.com/ramya-rao-a/go-outline v0.0.0-20200117021646-2a048b4510eb
golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil
github.com/ramya-rao-a/go-outline
ajayk@ajays-MacBook-Pro-2 code % /usr/local/go/bin/go get -v github.com/cweill/gotests/gotests
go: downloading github.com/cweill/gotests v1.6.0
go: downloading golang.org/x/tools v0.0.0-20191109212701-97ad0ed33101
golang.org/x/tools/internal/semver
github.com/cweill/gotests/internal/models
golang.org/x/tools/go/ast/astutil
golang.org/x/tools/internal/fastwalk
golang.org/x/tools/internal/module
golang.org/x/tools/internal/span
golang.org/x/tools/go/internal/packagesdriver
golang.org/x/tools/go/internal/gcimporter
github.com/cweill/gotests/internal/goparser
github.com/cweill/gotests/internal/input
golang.org/x/tools/internal/gopathwalk
github.com/cweill/gotests/internal/render/bindata
github.com/cweill/gotests/templates
github.com/cweill/gotests/internal/render
golang.org/x/tools/go/gcexportdata
golang.org/x/tools/go/packages
golang.org/x/tools/internal/imports
golang.org/x/tools/imports
github.com/cweill/gotests/internal/output
github.com/cweill/gotests
github.com/cweill/gotests/gotests/process
github.com/cweill/gotests/gotests
ajayk@ajays-MacBook-Pro-2 code % /usr/local/go/bin/go get -v github.com/fatih/gomodifytags
go: downloading github.com/fatih/gomodifytags v1.13.0
go: downloading github.com/fatih/structtag v1.2.0
go: downloading github.com/fatih/camelcase v1.0.0
go: downloading golang.org/x/tools v0.0.0-20180824175216-6c1c5e93cdc1
github.com/fatih/camelcase
github.com/fatih/structtag
golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil
github.com/fatih/gomodifytags
ajayk@ajays-MacBook-Pro-2 code % /usr/local/go/bin/go get -v github.com/josharian/impl
go: downloading github.com/josharian/impl v1.0.0
go: downloading golang.org/x/tools v0.0.0-20200522201501-cb1345f3a375
go: downloading golang.org/x/mod v0.2.0
go: downloading golang.org/x/xerrors v0.0.0-20191204190536-9bdfabe68543
golang.org/x/mod/semver
golang.org/x/xerrors/internal
golang.org/x/tools/internal/event/label
golang.org/x/tools/internal/fastwalk
golang.org/x/xerrors
golang.org/x/tools/go/ast/astutil
golang.org/x/tools/internal/event/keys
golang.org/x/tools/internal/gopathwalk
golang.org/x/mod/module
golang.org/x/tools/internal/event/core
golang.org/x/tools/internal/event
golang.org/x/tools/internal/gocommand
golang.org/x/tools/internal/imports
golang.org/x/tools/imports
github.com/josharian/impl
ajayk@ajays-MacBook-Pro-2 code % /usr/local/go/bin/go get -v github.com/haya14busa/goplay/cmd/goplay
go: downloading github.com/haya14busa/goplay v1.0.0
go: downloading github.com/skratchdot/open-golang v0.0.0-20200116055534-eef842397966
github.com/skratchdot/open-golang/open
github.com/haya14busa/goplay
github.com/haya14busa/goplay/cmd/goplay
ajayk@ajays-MacBook-Pro-2 code % /usr/local/go/bin/go get -v github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv
go: downloading github.com/go-delve/delve v1.6.1
go: downloading github.com/sirupsen/logrus v1.6.0
go: downloading github.com/spf13/cobra v0.0.0-20170417170307-b6cb39589372
go: downloading github.com/mattn/go-isatty v0.0.3
go: downloading gopkg.in/yaml.v2 v2.2.1
go: downloading github.com/google/go-dap v0.5.0
go: downloading golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20200625212154-ddb9806d33ae
go: downloading github.com/cosiner/argv v0.1.0
go: downloading github.com/mattn/go-colorable v0.0.0-20170327083344-ded68f7a9561
go: downloading github.com/peterh/liner v0.0.0-20170317030525-88609521dc4b
go: downloading github.com/hashicorp/golang-lru v0.5.4
go: downloading golang.org/x/arch v0.0.0-20190927153633-4e8777c89be4
go: downloading go.starlark.net v0.0.0-20200821142938-949cc6f4b097
go: downloading github.com/cpuguy83/go-md2man v1.0.10
go: downloading github.com/spf13/pflag v0.0.0-20170417173400-9e4c21054fa1
go: downloading github.com/inconshreveable/mousetrap v1.0.0
go: downloading github.com/konsorten/go-windows-terminal-sequences v1.0.3
go: downloading github.com/russross/blackfriday v1.5.2
go: downloading github.com/russross/blackfriday v1.6.0
golang.org/x/sys/internal/unsafeheader
github.com/hashicorp/golang-lru/simplelru
go.starlark.net/internal/spell
github.com/mattn/go-isatty
golang.org/x/sys/unix
github.com/cosiner/argv
github.com/go-delve/delve/pkg/goversion
gopkg.in/yaml.v2
github.com/go-delve/delve/pkg/dwarf/util
github.com/go-delve/delve/pkg/dwarf/regnum
github.com/go-delve/delve/pkg/version
github.com/go-delve/delve/pkg/astutil
github.com/go-delve/delve/pkg/elfwriter
golang.org/x/arch/arm64/arm64asm
github.com/go-delve/delve/pkg/terminal/colorize
golang.org/x/arch/x86/x86asm
github.com/go-delve/delve/pkg/dwarf/op
github.com/go-delve/delve/pkg/dwarf/line
github.com/go-delve/delve/pkg/dwarf/frame
github.com/peterh/liner
go.starlark.net/syntax
github.com/google/go-dap
net/rpc
github.com/spf13/pflag
github.com/russross/blackfriday
github.com/go-delve/delve/pkg/dwarf/godwarf
net/rpc/jsonrpc
github.com/go-delve/delve/pkg/dwarf/loclist
github.com/go-delve/delve/pkg/dwarf/reader
go.starlark.net/resolve
github.com/cpuguy83/go-md2man/md2man
github.com/spf13/cobra
go.starlark.net/internal/compile
github.com/sirupsen/logrus
github.com/spf13/cobra/doc
github.com/go-delve/delve/pkg/config
go.starlark.net/starlark
github.com/go-delve/delve/pkg/logflags
github.com/go-delve/delve/pkg/gobuild
github.com/go-delve/delve/pkg/proc
github.com/go-delve/delve/pkg/proc/winutil
github.com/go-delve/delve/pkg/proc/amd64util
github.com/go-delve/delve/pkg/proc/native
github.com/go-delve/delve/service/api
github.com/go-delve/delve/pkg/proc/core/minidump
github.com/go-delve/delve/pkg/proc/linutil
github.com/go-delve/delve/pkg/locspec
github.com/go-delve/delve/pkg/proc/core
github.com/go-delve/delve/pkg/proc/gdbserial
github.com/go-delve/delve/service/debugger
github.com/go-delve/delve/service
github.com/go-delve/delve/service/rpc1
github.com/go-delve/delve/service/rpc2
github.com/go-delve/delve/pkg/terminal/starbind
github.com/go-delve/delve/service/rpccommon
github.com/go-delve/delve/pkg/terminal
github.com/go-delve/delve/service/dap
github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv/cmds
github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv
ajayk@ajays-MacBook-Pro-2 code % /usr/local/go/bin/go get -v -d github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@master
go: downloading github.com/go-delve/delve v1.6.2-0.20210528182153-b2afb7cd209e
ajayk@ajays-MacBook-Pro-2 code % /usr/local/go/bin/go get -v honnef.co/go/tools/cmd/staticcheck
go: downloading honnef.co/go/tools v0.2.0
go: downloading golang.org/x/tools v0.1.0
go: downloading golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20210119212857-b64e53b001e4
go: downloading golang.org/x/mod v0.3.0
golang.org/x/mod/semver
honnef.co/go/tools/internal/sync
honnef.co/go/tools/sarif
honnef.co/go/tools/knowledge
honnef.co/go/tools/printf
golang.org/x/tools/internal/lsp/fuzzy
golang.org/x/sys/execabs
golang.org/x/tools/internal/event/label
honnef.co/go/tools/internal/robustio
honnef.co/go/tools/lintcmd/version
golang.org/x/tools/go/ast/astutil
golang.org/x/tools/go/ast/inspector
golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil
golang.org/x/tools/go/internal/gcimporter
golang.org/x/tools/internal/typesinternal
honnef.co/go/tools/internal/go/gcimporter
golang.org/x/tools/go/types/objectpath
golang.org/x/tools/go/internal/cgo
golang.org/x/tools/internal/event/keys
honnef.co/go/tools/internal/renameio
honnef.co/go/tools/pattern
honnef.co/go/tools/unused/typemap
honnef.co/go/tools/internal/cache
golang.org/x/tools/internal/event/core
golang.org/x/tools/internal/event
golang.org/x/tools/internal/gocommand
golang.org/x/tools/internal/analysisinternal
honnef.co/go/tools/go/ast/astutil
golang.org/x/tools/go/types/typeutil
golang.org/x/tools/go/loader
golang.org/x/tools/go/internal/packagesdriver
golang.org/x/tools/internal/packagesinternal
honnef.co/go/tools/go/types/typeutil
golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis
honnef.co/go/tools/go/ir
honnef.co/go/tools/analysis/lint
golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/passes/inspect
honnef.co/go/tools/config
golang.org/x/tools/go/gcexportdata
golang.org/x/tools/go/packages
honnef.co/go/tools/analysis/edit
honnef.co/go/tools/go/loader
honnef.co/go/tools/internal/passes/buildir
honnef.co/go/tools/go/ir/irutil
honnef.co/go/tools/analysis/facts/nilness
honnef.co/go/tools/analysis/facts/typedness
honnef.co/go/tools/analysis/facts
honnef.co/go/tools/analysis/report
honnef.co/go/tools/analysis/code
honnef.co/go/tools/internal/sharedcheck
honnef.co/go/tools/unused
honnef.co/go/tools/stylecheck
honnef.co/go/tools/quickfix
honnef.co/go/tools/simple
honnef.co/go/tools/staticcheck
honnef.co/go/tools/lintcmd/runner
honnef.co/go/tools/lintcmd
honnef.co/go/tools/cmd/staticcheck
ajayk@ajays-MacBook-Pro-2 code % /usr/local/go/bin/go get -v golang.org/x/tools/gopls
ajayk@ajays-MacBook-Pro-2 code %
```

Answer (score 0):

The problems are from your `go` environment variables. `go get` and `go install` commands would attempt to install packages on the path specified by the `GOPATH` and `GOBIN` environment variables respectively. If those paths are incorrectly specified (as in my own case) or not specified at all, `go` would try to install the packages on the `/User` directory which, in most cases, does not have `write` permission. So, follow the [official instruction here](https://go.dev/doc/code#remote) to properly setup the variables.

> The install directory is controlled by the GOPATH and GOBIN environment
> variables. If GOBIN is set, binaries are installed to that directory. If
> GOPATH is set, binaries are installed to the bin subdirectory of the
> first directory in the GOPATH list. Otherwise, binaries are installed to
> the bin subdirectory of the default GOPATH ($HOME/go or
> %USERPROFILE%\go).You can use the go env command to portably set the default value for an
> environment variable for future go commands: `$ go env -w GOBIN=/somewhere/else/bin$`

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem because the `GOPATH` was wrong in my MacOS.

The origin wrong `GOPATH` was `/root/go/`, but actually it is `/Users/your-account/go` in MacOS. It only has `read-only` permission for `/root/go`.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you have some misspell.
Check spelling
Gopath is /User**s**/ajayk/code/go Not /User